# App crashes on iPhone 5 when calling the Viewcontroller in delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, iphone-5

I have a project that works well in other simulators including The New iPad. However, with the iPhone5, it crashes when calling the Viewcontroller in delegate
I don't know why this error happens. Please let me know if you discover any possible causes in the code below:

```
self.rootviewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil]; 
self.rootNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
self.rootNavController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
[window addSubview:rootNavController.view];'
```

Please see image below:
[image: error]

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you symbolicated the crash log?

Comment: You should add a generic exception breakpoint: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions It will help you a lot to debug the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do something wrong with the creation of your `UINavigationController`, try the following code to replace yours in your `AppDelegate.m` :

**EDIT** add code to display and remove splashscreen with `UIViewController`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Create View Controller
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];

    // Create Navigation Controller
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

    // Create Navigation Controller
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // SplashScreen
    [self displaySplashscreen];

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - SplashScreen Methods
- (void)displaySplashscreen
{
    // Create View
    self.splashscreenViewController = [[SplashscreenViewController alloc] init];

    // Display Splashscreen
    [_window addSubview:_splashscreenViewController.view];

    // Dismiss Splashscreen
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissSplashscreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0f]; // Modify the time
}

- (void)dismissSplashscreen
{
    // Splashscreen Animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                     animations:^{
                         _splashscreenViewController.view.alpha = 0.0f;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [_splashscreenViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The SplashViewController is a class implementing the UIViewController 

It's used to show the loading situation with UIActivityIndicatorView 



when running the project with these codes ,nothing happens and it doesn't show the rootViewController


[Reference](http://i44.tinypic.com/28jw7ra.png)

But When adding this line ,it crashes 

     code:[window addSubView:rootNavController.view];

[Reference 2](http://i43.tinypic.com/119xxj4.png)

this image shows the debug console

[Error](http://i40.tinypic.com/2wdpxlg.png)

Comment: Ok I don't see correctly your code. I will edit my answer with the correct way to call and dismiss splashscreen